# Wanted the absolute value, i.e., |a-b| in the subtracting function

Tags: c

Let a = 4 and b = 5

- on adding a+b = 9
- on subtracting a-b = -1

But I want the absolute value of the answer, i.e., |a-b|=4-5=1. All I am getting is a negative 1.

How can I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void add(int*a,int*b){
    int c = *a+*b;
    printf("%d\n",c);
}
void subtract(int*a,int*b){
    int c = *a-*b;
    printf("%d\n",c);
}
int main() {
    int a, b;    //enter the value of a and b
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    add(&a,&b);
    subtract(&a,&b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/

Answer (score 0):

simply put a condition using ternary operator.
replace assigning to c as following.

int c = *a > *b ? *a - *b : *b - *a;